# Swift TabbarViewController action based on alert selection. shouldSelect and didSelect are not helping

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I want to change the tab in tabbar based on an alert selection (Alert - Are you sure you want to leave this page. CASE - Yes - change the view as per tabbar selected.CASE - No - Don't do anything. Stay on same page(tabbar index).

I tried using tabbarcontrollerdelegate method didselect and shouldselect, but not able to have it working.

```swift
 func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

var decision : Bool?
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You are in middle of a Quiz", message: "Do you want to end the Quiz in between !",         preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { _ in
            // do nothing.
            decision = false
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes",
                                      style: UIAlertAction.Style.default,
                                      handler: {(_: UIAlertAction!) in
                                        decision = true
            // go to clicked tabbar view                          
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return decision!

    }
```

This code is not working because before getting into alert selection, didselect returns bool (crashes in above case). What could be an alternate to solving this problem ie on tabbar click, the view should change only after user reconfirms that he wants to leave the current page (through an alert action).

Answer (score 0):

In `shouldSelect viewController` method check whether viewController is your destination view controller. If not return `true`, if yes present the alert and return `false`.

If `No` selected the alert, do nothing. If `Yes` selected, assign the destination view controller as [`selectedViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621172-selectedviewcontroller) in `tabBarController`

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController is DestinationViewController {            
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You are in middle of a Quiz", message: "Do you want to end the Quiz in between !",         preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { action in
            tabBarController.selectedViewController = viewController
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```